# Optimize Oracle join query on a table with large number of rows

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have a source table and an identical target table, in them we have a Rate per day, per customer, per period and we have 48 periods 
for each day, so for a single customer we have 48 rows per day.

```
tblSource
SD          UpdateDate            CustId  Period   Rate
01/01/2013  01/01/2013 14:30:29    1245    1       2.3 
01/01/2013  01/01/2013 14:32:29    1245    2       4.3 
01/01/2013  01/01/2013 14:34:29    1245    3       2.1 
.....
01/01/2013  01/01/2013 14:34:29    1245    48       2.1 

tblTarget
SD          UpdateDate            CustId  Period   Rate
01/01/2013  01/01/2013 14:30:29    1245    1       2.3 
01/01/2013  01/01/2013 14:32:29    1245    2       4.3 
01/01/2013  01/01/2013 14:34:29    1245    3       2.1 
.....
01/01/2013  01/01/2013 14:34:29    1245    48       2.1
```

I am writing a script which will compare the two table and insert any row that exists on the source table but not on the target into the target table.

The below is my query which works fine but my problem is that **both the source and target tables have over 4 millions rows** in them so the process is taking too long, we have index on the target and source table on SD, CustId, and Period columns.

Is there any other way of writing this query or optimizing it so we can improve the speed.

```
SELECT s.SD, s.UpdateDate, s.CustId, s.Period, s.Rate 
FROM tblScource s
LEFT JOIN tblTarget t ON t.sd = s.SD AND s.CustId = t.CustId AND s.Period = t.Rate 
WHERE t.SD IS NULL and t.custId IS NULL
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using profiling or explain plan to see what your query is really doing?

Comment: I am not able to do it at the moment.

Comment: Your query looks OK.  I assume that most of the records match between the source and target table, in which case you would *not* want to use indexes.  You probably want a plan with full table scans and a hash join.  But without the explain plan we can only guess what's happening.  Also, how long does the process take?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  s.SD, s.UpdateDate, s.CustId, s.Period, s.Rate 
FROM    tblScource s
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    tblTarget t
            WHERE   t.sd = s.SD
            AND     s.CustId = t.CustId
            AND     s.Period = t.Rate
            AND     t.SD IS NULL
            AND     t.custId IS NULL
        )
;
```

Answer (score 0):

can you show us the explain plan please ?
try to create table as select , in order to see how much time the SELECT process consumes ,

```
create table as SELECT s.SD, s.UpdateDate, s.CustId, s.Period, s.Rate 
FROM tblScource s
LEFT JOIN tblTarget t ON t.sd = s.SD AND s.CustId = t.CustId AND s.Period = t.Rate 
WHERE t.SD IS NULL and t.custId IS NULL;
```

if it ain't takes much time than the problem is probably on the target table , try to drop the indexes on the target table before the merging and then recreate it afterwards.